# Creating a seperate object and editing it from an object reference in Java

Tags: java, string, oop, object, pass-by-reference

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(String a) {this.a = a;}
    public void editString() {a = a + "anything";}
    public String getString() {return a;}
}

public class test {
    public test() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass("stuff");
        MyClass myNewClass = myClass;
        myNewClass.editString();
        System.out.println(myClass.getString());
        System.out.println(myNewClass.getString());
    }
}
```

Both objects will return the same thing ("stuffanything"), I imagine this is because Java passes object variables by reference, is there anyway to avoid this? I only want to edit the string for myNewClass.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myClass` and `myNewClass` refer to exactly the same object. Modifying one's state will modify the other's. What you want is a copy of the same object. One way to do this is by defining a copy constructor that copies the field from a given object:

```
public MyClass(MyClass myClass) {
    this.a = myClass.a;
}
```

Then you can create a copy of the object as follows:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass("stuff");
MyClass myNewClass = new MyClass(myClass);
myNewClass.editString();
System.out.println(myClass.getString());
System.out.println(myNewClass.getString());
```

which outputs:

```
stuff
stuffanything
```

Comment: That's great thank you, but then MyClass myClass = new MyClass("stuff"); doesn't work? How would I initially create the class then?

Comment: @ErlangBestLanguage You can keep both constructors.

Comment: Wow I had no idea you could do that thank you so much!